# height css not working in IE and firefox

Tags: html, css

So the problem is the object tag. it simply refuses to scale heightwise. chrome works perfect. IE and firefox it stays the default height. I am having a really hard time finding cross-browser code. From what I have found from other threads and sites is that the parent container needs to have a height set. so that is why you see height settings on html and body and the `<div id="calendar">`. Although I understand the theory it still doesn't work.

side note: the reason for the inline css is cause that's where i do my css testing. and i didn't make a fiddle because the object is like 80+ files and i don't know how to use jsfiddle that well and kinda feel like that isn't going to be able to get the calendar in there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%" >
<body style="height: 100%" >
    <form >
    <div id="calendar" style="height: 70%">
        <object data="calendar.php" width="50%" style="height: 100%"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sparky672 can you take back the down vote as i did what you asked and is now undeserved.

Comment: The reason for the down-vote has nothing to do with your previous comment.  It has to do with dumping the entire contents of your page into the question instead of a small concise example that demonstrates the problem... and for poor grammar... and not wanting to take the time to learn how to construct a jsFiddle.

Comment: really?! most of the threads i've read on here people have asked for more content. i put everything on here in case something in my css or elsewhere was causing the problem. and as far as poor grammer/spelling......i'm not even gonna start

Comment: I'm trying to help you so let's not argue about your points.  The voting system here is not designed to punish, it's designed to make for a higher quality site.  Don't you think a concise example that demonstrates the problem will be more likely to attract many answers, than all the code from the entire page? See http://sscce.org

Comment: This version validates:  http://jsfiddle.net/zu9cL/

Comment: @Sparky672 oh i see how you can use jsfiddle for objects now. i didn't think about just showing the box. sigh. and i totally see the error i made as well. i apologize for my lack of experience. thanks again for all the help.

Comment: It's your prerogative to accept any answer you wish, but since you already had `html` and `body` at `height: 100%`, mine actually identified the root issues (`form` height not set and invalid HTML).

Comment: @Sparky672 what's invalid about it?! it's the same other then you added height to form. and put all the css in an external sheet vs inline which i stated i do for testing purposes.

Comment: The HTML I identified in my answer below was "invalid" as per the W3C Validator & Spec (please read my answer).  The `object` tag was not properly closed and the `height` attribute was not properly set.  Also, the CSS `height` for the parent `form` was not set.  My jsFiddle only started working after I fixed these two issues.  Placing the CSS inline or externally has nothing to do with anything.  Mr. Alien's answer (`html` & `body` `height: 100%`) was not much different than you already had posted in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is the `object tag` so where's the tag? And for the question you asked why you need this

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

is because when you use `height: 70%;` for child element than the question arises `70%` of what? So when you define height to parent in `%` it defines `70%` of `100%`

Comment: It's not easy to spot but it's inside the `div` called `#calendar`.

Comment: the object tag is in the calendar div. and yes i agree. i understand the concept of the 70% of 100%. i said that in the description

Comment: @Sparky672 oh I finally searched pheeew

Comment: so the object is taking up 100% of the 70% i have sectioned off from the 100% of the page

Comment: I see `<object data="calendar.php" width="50%" style="height: 100%"/>` inside there.

Comment: ? should i have called it something else?!

Comment: @Sparky672 and Jon sorry guys my bad, need to wear glasses :p

Comment: He also already has inline CSS that defines `html` and `body` at `height: 100%`.

Comment: right i do it inline for testing purposes. otherwise i'm ctrl-tab constantly to change pages and that's not productive.

Comment: @Jon anyways this answer doesn't help much I see too much of negatives in your CSS, why?

Comment: @Mr.Alien most likely lack of experience on my part but for the margins that's how i've been going about positioning the components. so like margin-left: -10px; would pull the left wall of the component 10px to the right.

Comment: Do you know CSS positioning concept well?

Comment: not really i guess no? :(
I have a much easier time understanding php and java. i feel like css should be a walk in the park but with each browser having it's own css standards it's proving to be a huge challenge. i just googled css positioning and will definitely look into it more. i wasn't aware that you could actually position the component with that. i thought it was just "fixed, relative, absolute".

Comment: @Jon It's pretty big concept than you think, none of the browser has it's own css rules unless and until you use proprietary style properties, it should be cross browser. learn css positioning, will take your knowledge to another level

Comment: @Jon, If you think cross-browser coding is a problem now, you should have been doing it back when IE 4 was popular.  Anyway...  each browser does not have their own standards... they all are supposed to follow the W3C standards.  As long as your code also follows W3C standards, 99% of your problems are gone.

Comment: @Jon, Also see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) and [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Comment: @Sparky672 Oh ya how can I forget lovely super box model

Comment: ok i ran the code through the w3c validator and it turns out <object> cannot self close. so that was 1 problem. it doesn't like the width being a percentage but that works just fine cross-browser. should i ignore that error?

Comment: @Jon As far as I know websites do use object but still it is a not valid tag under any html specification...

Comment: @Jon, the Box Model is not optional. [As per this page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), _"The CSS box model describes the rectangular boxes that are generated for elements in the document tree and laid out according to the visual formatting model."_

Comment: @Mr.Alien validator.w3.org didn't error on it after i put in a seperate closing tag. ( <object></object> ) is there other options? at first i used <embed> but firefox didn't like that and from the documentation i read it's because of plug-ins

Comment: @Jon, if the validator says it's valid, then it's valid and should work in all browsers, barring browser bugs.

Comment: @Sparky672 yeah css box model is a neat short-hand way. i am not using that because i want this to be as simple as possible for my client if they should go in a dink around with stuff. i like being verbose.

Comment: @Jon, you misunderstand Box Model entirely.  It's not "shorthand" for anything.  It's simply this:  _"The CSS box model describes the rectangular boxes that are generated for elements in the document tree and laid out according to the visual formatting model."_  In other words, the Box Model describes how your CSS rules get applied to your elements.

Comment: margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
this is short-hand based on the box model. yes?!

Comment: @Jon, please take the time to [read the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).  Box Model has nothing to do with "shorthand".

Comment: Ya learn things what me and sparky told, you'll be done with 90% of CSS

Comment: @Jon, "Box Model" is not optional.  All CSS just follows the "Box Model"... get it?

Comment: The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. exactly what i said pretty much. maybe your misunderstanding what i'm saying cause i'm not saying it perfectly enough for you. or your just trolling me. i don't know what the deal is but this is getting me no where.

Comment: @Sparky672 Ya we are not going to score any upvotes answering because we are busy here, so now upvoting comments is making us happy I guess hahaha

Comment: @Jon, why are we stuck on shorthand?... it does not matter to the browser or the Box Model.  Shorthand or Verbose... both are equally valid.

Comment: i don't know why were talking about this. i'm trying to work with you. so far i understand everything you've said but you keep saying i'm wrong.

Comment: You are only wrong if you think using shorthand has anything to do with the CSS Box Model.  The Box Model just describes how content, padding, border, and margin work with each other.

Comment: @Sparky672 ok. so i read through those links you sent me i should be able to figure it out then. assuming i'm not a complete idiot.

Comment: @Mr.Alien lols i have to go for awhile too. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code was also broken in Safari, but my solution seems to have fixed that.

This version validates:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/zu9cL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/zu9cL/)

Maybe it will work for you.  Generally, Explorer hates invalid code.

I believe you had two root problems.

- used `50%` within `width` attribute and improperly closed `<object>` tag (invalid HTML)
- failure to define `height` on parent element `<form>`

I used no inline CSS in my demo but feel free to put your CSS back "inline" if you wish, it will still work.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div id="calendar">
                <object data="calendar.php"></object>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body, form {
    height: 100%;
}
#calendar {
    height: 70%;
}
object {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

---

It all works the same with CSS placed "inline".

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zu9cL/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%;">
        <form style="height: 100%;">
            <div id="calendar" style="height: 70%;">
                <object data="calendar.php" style="height: 100%; width: 50%;"></object>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```